# Using ActionBarSherlock with monodroid

Tags: mono, xamarin.android, monodevelop

I have a few problems regarding using ActionBarSherlock example and mono for android.

Monodevelop does not recognize the ’Com’ namespace. I can compile without errors but the IDE does not recognize the namespaces and classes inside it.

[image]

Anybody else suffering from this issues?

Comment: I have the exact same problem. Did you figure it out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you referencing the DLL, or the Java Binding project?  There is a known bug for this: https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=6695. It looks like this bug has been fixed, just not released yet.

If you reference the DLL instead of the binding project you should get your Intellisense back.